# How to Create a virtual network interface and connect it to a bridge

Tags: networking, qemu

I am trying to create a network of virtal qemu machines and the host using a bridge on Arch Linux to test a distributed program I wrote. I have found many howtos on using the physical NIC of the host on the bridge to connect to the VMs. This works fine. However, I don't want the VMs to be visible to the outside network but rather create a virtual interface on the host to connect to the VMs. This is what I have tried so far after creating the bridge and starting the VMs on it:

```
ip tuntap add tap2 mode tap
ip link set tap2 up
ip addr add dev tap2 10.10.10.2/24
ip link set tap2 master br0
```

Since I can't reach the VMs from the host I must be missing something.
ip link output is:

```
➜  ~ ip link                         
[...]
7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:69:29:67:cb:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: tap2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:69:29:67:cb:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Also, the route is shown to be down:

```
➜  ~ ip route
[...]
10.10.10.0/24 dev tap2 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.2 linkdown
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up another virtual interface is not necessary since one can assign an IP to the bridge:

```
ip addr add dev br0 <ip>
```

This can then be used to communicate with the other devices on the bridge if these have IPs in the same subnet